# Can I prevent Windows event watcher created in PowerShell from disappearing with server logoff?

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I set up an event watcher running on Server 1 (where the needed applications are installed, Windows Server 2008 R2) to detect file creation events on Server 2 (where the shared files are stored). Both are on UNC paths. I use RDC/RDP to log into Server 1 and there I run PowerShell to create, register, and/or unregister the event watcher.

**Assumptions:** I've inferred such events should persist regardless of whether I'm logged in or not from reading about event watcher actions persisting across computer restarts.

**Behaviors:** In my case the watcher's actions only execute until I log out, and when I log back in the watcher is gone, or so I believe because I get this error when I try to unsubscribe from it...

```
Get-EventSubscriber : Event subscription with identifier 'FileToProcess' does not exist.
```

**Goal:** I want those wonderful `$OnEvent` actions triggering when a file is created, *no matter what*. UPDATE: especially while I'm logged out, and I'm usually logged out.

**Setup:**

```
$Monitor = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$Monitor.Path = $FolderToMonitor
$Monitor.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$Monitor.Filter = '*.*'

$SourceIdentifier = "FileToProcess"
$OnEvent = {...run a program in Server 1, write a file to Server 2, etc...}

# Unregister:
Unregister-Event $SourceIdentifier

# Register:
Register-ObjectEvent $Monitor Created -SourceIdentifier $SourceIdentifier -Action $OnEvent
```

**Conjecture:** When I log out, I don't mean disconnect. I log out and when I log back in I get a whole new Windows session. Maybe Windows isn't running on the server when I'm logged out? But I've read dozens of articles about event watchers and nobody mentioned that matters. Kind of important.

**Follow-ups:** If that's the real problem, then...

- I know Windows Task Scheduler can run tasks regardless of being logged in. Can't event watchers of some kind be told to do that too?
- Is there some way to log out without exiting Windows?
- How is it that everyone else seems to have persistent events (even sometimes complaining that unwanted events persist no matter what they do)?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at services. A [custom one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/october/windows-service-create-a-customizable-filesystemwatcher-windows-service) could watch filesystem and keeps running in the background.

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher` needs to be used by a process to work. By itself it will not survive a process kill or a system restart. You should look into hosting the `FileSystemWatcher` inside a process that will be started on system restart, such as a Windows Service.

Comment: Lasse and vonPryz, thanks, but if I understand "needs to be used by a process to work" and "keeps running in the background" correctly, then it sounds like those ideas would make my stuff more resilient but I'd still have the main problem which is no actions are triggering while I'm logged out (which is usually). Is that right?